# Intellij can't login to github

Tags: github, intellij-idea

After submitting my Github credentials, I see the following error, even though those credentials are correct:

[image]

<sup>*IntelliJ can't login to Github*</sup>

Comment: Can you login from the GitHub website directly using the same credentials?

Comment: If you have a two-factor authentication set up, you will need to request an API token. Change your "Auth type" to "Token" and request a new one, the rest should be easy.

Comment: In addition to @Somrlik 's answer, if you do not know which scopes are sufficient, here is the list: `gist, read:org, repo, workflow`

Answer (score 3):

Try using `github.com` as host address and your nickname as login.

Also, use the token instead of the credentials, this is supposed to be safer.

It should, in theory, work. If not, either:

1. You made a typo in your credentials.
2. The IDEA couldn't reach the host because its network messages were blocked on their path by a firewall or anything else. Make sure you can ping [github.com](http://github.com) and that the `HTTPS` (I think it's the on used here) port (`443`) isn't blocked by your gateway. You can also check for port `22` if you want to use `SSH`.